# Как добавить дату в MySQL БД? Получаю ошибку "(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... near '2017-08-10'')' at line 1")"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

При попытке добавить дату получаю ошибку "(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2017-08-10'')' at line 1")" но вот в коде нет у меня лишних скобок и не понятно почему получаю ошибку. При добавлении в БД без даты, все работает.

```
from MySQLdb import *

query = "INSERT INTO analytics.events (android_id, event_datetime) VALUES ( '%s', '%s');"

try:
    import datetime
    connection.cursor().execute(query, (1, datetime.date.today()))
    connection.commit()
except MySQLError as error:
    print(error)
    connection.rollback()
```

Comment: Посмотрите в General Log, как точно выглядит добравшийся до сервера запрос. Возможно, `datetime.date.today()` придётся дополнительно отформатировать - формат должен быть строго `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: `...VALUES ( '%s', '%s');"` - ошибка, `;` после скобки.

Comment: так она и стоит после скобки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в скобочках)) Хоть pycharm и ругается на запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно все же стало работать. АЛЛИЛУЙЯ
И datetime.date.today() правильно заполняет, если что)